# Display top 5 results PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, limit

I have creating a questionnaire through PHP. There are ten questions, each relating to a specific career. The code I have matches the user input for each question against each career. At the end of the questionnaire, the results match the users compatibility against the ten careers, giving the match as a percentage. I want to display the top 5 results but am unsure what code to use and where to use it. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Footballer
$career2sequence1 = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `q1` FROM `careers` WHERE    `careerid` = '2'"), 0);
?>

<?php
$career2result1 = $question1/$career2sequence1;
if ($career2result1>1) {
$career2result1 = $career2sequence1/$question1
?>

<?php 
}
?>

<?php
$careername1 = 'Nursing ';
$careername2 = 'Footballer ';
$careername3 = 'Dentist ';
$careername4 = 'Hairdressing ';
$careername5 = 'IT ';
$careername6 = 'Trade ';
$careername7 = 'Doctor ';
$careername8 = 'Teacher ';
$careername9 = 'Sales Assistant ';
$careername10 = 'Cook/Chef ';
?>

<h4>

<?php
$nursing = array("Nursing", $result1, "% ", "$link1");
$footballer = array("Footballer", $result2, "% ", "$link2");
$dentist = array("Dentist", $result3, "% ", "$link3");
$hairdresser = array("Hairdresser", $result4, "% ", "$link4");
$IT = array("IT", $result5, "% ", "$link5");
$Trade = array("Trade", $result6, "% ", "$link6");
$Doctor = array("Doctor", $result7, "% ", "$link7");
$Teacher = array("Teacher", $result8, "% ", "$link8");
$SalesAssistant = array("Sales Assistant", $result9, "% ", "$link9");
$CookChef = array("Cook/Chef", $result10, "% ", "$link10");

$items = array($nursing, $footballer, $dentist, $hairdresser, $IT, $Trade, $Doctor,    $Teacher, $SalesAssistant, $CookChef);

foreach ($items as $item) {
$item[1].'<-'.$item[0].'<br>';;
}

function compare($a, $b) {
if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a[1] > $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($items, 'compare');

foreach ($items as $item) {

echo implode(' ',$item).'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it directly in your query with LIMIT.

```
SELECT `q1` FROM `careers` WHERE `careerid` = '2' LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: top 5 would be `LIMIT 0, 5` (offset, per page)

Comment: But there is a lot of individual queries as there is career 1 sequence 1 right up to career 1 sequence 10 and there is 10 careers. It is then tested against the users results for each question

Comment: @KerriPower - instead of doing a lot of querys you should execute one query and fetch the results you want from that query.

Comment: I never considered that; how would I do this? Sorry, im just a bit new to all this PHP stuff

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to achieve that. I would suggest reading up on arrays, different kinds of loops (while, foreach etc) and PDO (alternative (=BETTER) way of connecting to a db instead of mysql_*). If you can handle these things you have come far!